# Make mysql query to find all people from some table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table `Person` and I have another 3 `Doctor`, `Policeman`, `Lawyer`.... these 3 tables have `idPerson` from which they take the common attributes like name surname etc.... If I want to find all people that are either doctor or lawyer with their common information from table `Person`, how can I do that?

I tried something like that (played by putting all combination Right join, left join, inner join)

```
SELECT Person.* 
FROM Person 
RIGHT JOIN doctor ON doctor.idPerson = person.idPerson 
LEFT JOIN lawyer ON lawyer.idPerson = person.idPerson
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using joins, you may find it simpler to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln
FROM Person
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE Doctor.idPerson = Person.idPerson
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Lawyer WHERE Lawyer.idPerson = Person.idPerson
)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! And all other answers worked but I think that your answer is the rightest way to do what I asked... Thanks all for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Person.* 
FROM Person 
LEFT JOIN doctor ON doctor.idPerson = person.idPerson 
LEFT JOIN lawyer ON lawyer.idPerson = person.idPerson
WHERE lawyer.idPerson IS NOT NULL 
OR doctor.idPerson IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Person.* FROM Person 
left outer JOIN doctor ON doctor.idPerson = person.idPerson 
LEFT outer JOIN lawyer ON lawyer.idPerson = person.idPerson
where doctor.personid is not null
or laywer.personid is not null
```